# Laravel Eloquent Count multip

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I currently have:

```
  $emails = Email::select('username', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
        ->groupBy('username')
        ->get();
```

Returning:

```
     {'username' => 'example', 'total'=>'120' }
```

What I trying to do is to also get a count of a certain row value, where row value is equal to 1, to obtain:

```
      {'username' => 'example', 'total'=>'120', 'sent' => '23' }
```

Like a :

```
     DB::raw('count(sentitems) as sent WHERE sentitems = 1')
```

but of course it won't work this way .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you mean something like this:

```
$emails = Email::select('username', DB::raw('count(*) as total'), DB::raw('count(case sentitems when 1 then 1 else null end) as sent')))
    ->groupBy('username')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

What can the row value be if it isn't 1? If the only possible values are 0 and 1, you can simply use `sum(sentitems)`. If other values are possible, you do `sum(if(sentitems = 1, 1, 0))`

Comment: Didn't thought of summing them, great idea, but for the general case, I will accept the second answer. Thank you guys.